# Is there a way to move arrow key to left on Windows Popup?

Tags: autohotkey

I am writing a script which will allow PowerShell to run in admin mode but when I run Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass, Windows displays a popup and I use my left arrow key to move to the yes button and press enter.

The problem I am facing is that it does not move to the left or press enter when I run the script as follows.

```
RunWait PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command "C:\Users\%A_UserName%\Desktop\Script.ps1";
Send {Left}
Sleep, 5000
Send {Enter}
```

I am expecting it to actually move to the OK button on the left and press enter but nothing actually happens.

Answer (score 1):

- If you run PowerShell in admin mode your script needs also to be [run
  in this mode](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs).
- Unlike Run, [RunWait](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) will wait until the program (in
  this case PowerShell.exe) finishes before continuing (= sending
  commands to the popup window). To bypass this problem use [SetTimer](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm#Examples).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured out a solution to my problem by running the .ahk in Admin Mode and it worked like a gem. Thanks though!